# I am having troubles with sapply in R

Tags: r, sapply

I have a list with 5 elements. Each element is a dataframe with the same 3 columns:probe.id, gene.name, and variance. As practice, I wish to extract the variance column from list element and rbind it with an empty matrix. Here is my code:

```
top100 <- c()
top100 <- rbind(top100, sapply(varianceList,function(x){
 x$variance
}))
```

The problem is that I get a matrix with one row, and each cell has a huge amount of values. So instead of having:

```
345   5667   ...   567
34    98     ...   50
...   ...    ...   ...
```

I get:

```
c(345,34,..)   c(5667, 98,...)  ... c(567, 50,...)
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated because collaborators often send send large lists with different sizes. Hence, I would like to be able to automate processes without knowing in advance the size of a list.Thank you!

Comment: what is the expected output format? try `sapply(varianceList, '[[', 'variance')` or `lapply(varianceList, '[[', 'variance')` or post a sample of the data

Comment: Or put everything into a single data frame by `d <- reshape2::melt(varianceList,id.vars = colnames(varianceList[[1]]))`, which will simplify further data processing

Comment: I guess the data frames have different row numbers, so you don't get a matrix shape. You would get the expected result, if every list element had the same number of variance values.

Answer (score 2):

The function you supply as the second argument to `sapply` needs to have a fixed length and type of output if you want `sapply` to return a matrix or vector, otherwise it returns a list, which is what you are getting.   Hence, `sapply` is amenable to functions like `min`, `max`, `var`, `fivenum`,`range`, etc. and not so amenable with `[`, `[[`, and `$`, unless you can guarantee that the data.frames or matrices included in the first argument of `sapply` all have the same dimensions.

Comment: You could then `unlist` the result andor do.call `c` to combine the elements into a long vector.